# How to get Tag component to know that it is wrapped under Tag Group component without using props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

So I have two components: Tag and TagGroup. When Tag component is used alone, I want that component to use `<div>` tag and when Tag is wrapped inside of TagGroup, which means more than 1 Tag is being used, then I want it to use `<li>` tag. With my current design, I used context to pass prop `groupUpTags` to Tag component. When `groupUpTags` is true then Tag component will use `<li>` tag, if false, `<div>` will be used. Currently, it doesn't even work properly as whether I wrap Tag component under TagGroup or not `<li>` tag is always being used. My question is, is there a way to get Tag component to render `<li>` tag when wrapped inside TagGroup without using any props and render `<div>` tag when used alone? My current design look little too messy.
https://codesandbox.io/s/tag-group-s07oyh?file=/src/App.tsx

App.tsx

```
import "./styles.css";
import React from "react";
import { TagGroupContextInterface, TagGroupContext } from "./TagGroupContext";

export interface TagGroupInterface extends TagGroupContextInterface {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

const Tag = () => {
  const context = React.useContext(TagGroupContext);
  return context.groupUpTags ? (
    <li className="tag">Tag</li>
  ) : (
    <div className="tag">Tag</div>
  );
};

const TagGroup = ({ groupUpTags = true, children }: TagGroupInterface) => {
  const context = React.useMemo(
    () => ({
      groupUpTags
    }),
    [groupUpTags]
  );

  return (
    <TagGroupContext.Provider value={context}>
      <div>
        <ul>{React.Children.map(children, (child) => child)}</ul>
      </div>
    </TagGroupContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <TagGroup>
        <Tag />
        <Tag />
        <Tag />
      </TagGroup>
    </div>
  );
}
```

TagGroupContext.tsx

```
import React from "react";

export interface TagGroupContextInterface {
  groupUpTags?: boolean;
}

const defaultTagGroupContext: TagGroupContextInterface = {
  groupUpTags: true
};

export const TagGroupContext = React.createContext<TagGroupContextInterface>(
  defaultTagGroupContext
);
```

Comment: `without using props` But why? That's what props are for.

Answer (score 0):

## Keep your components more deterministic

A Tag component should probably always return a simple tag in a div or a span whatever you need for the stand alone tag to work.

I would then add the li inside the list component since thats the moment you need the li. when you code a Tag it shouldn't know about the parents.

Probably something like this in your Tag Group

```
{Children.map(children, (child, i) => {
  <li key={i}>{child}</li>;
})}
```

note: don't use "i" as a key its not reliable. Use a uid from the tag itself.

Comment: So let's say Tag has its own id. Would it look something like this? `<li key={child.id}>{child}</li>`

Comment: It's actually returning `<li><div>tag label</div></li>`, but I need it to be `<li>Tag label</li>`

Comment: if your tag in this instance is just a string then put it all in list component. do not use child component since you are not actually using the the tag component.

Comment: Tag component will become more complex. This one I just created for quick example. But when I think about scalability and maintainability in the long run, I think it makes sense to go with `<li><div>tag label</div></li>` approach.